# php var_export object - forgot to serialize before storing

Tags: php, object, serialization, import

I have a project where last developer forgot to serialize objects before storing them into database. Now I have:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'id' => '1',
   'name' => 'John',
   'first_name' => 'John',
   'middle_name' => 'Montel',
))
```

I want to do that in professional way and get back object from this variable.
I want to access this object data in classic object accessing way $obj->name;
I know it's pretty easy to do when object is serialized before. But now I have what I have.

Did a google research for 2 hours - have no ideas for now. Thanks for any help !

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29361

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a serialized form obtained using [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), which returns valid PHP code. From the manual:

> var_export — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a
>   variable

If the class name in the serialized string would have been 'X', like 'X::__set_state...', you could have defined the '__set_state' method in 'X' and the code would be:

```
$serializedObj = "X::__set_state(array('id' => '1','name' => 'John',...))";
eval('$myObj = '.$serializedObj).';'
```

after which you could do:

```
$name = $myObj->name;
```

Since the class is 'stdClass', you have 2 options in my opinion:

1. Replace `stdClass::__set_state(` and the last `)` in your variable
   with empty string and `eval` the remaining array.
2. Replace `stdClass` with you own class `X` and define the `__set_state` method in `X`.

Comment: I did that with:

$array=eval('return '.str_replace(array('stdClass::__set_state(','))'), array('',')'), $var).';');
echo $array['id'];

but still looking for more objective workaround